# IndexedDB - IDBObjectStore.get with IDBKeyRange - request only returns single object?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

According to [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBObjectStore/get):

> ```
> var request = objectStore.get(key);
> ```
>
> #### Parameters
>
> *key*
>
> - The key or key range that identifies the record to be retrieved.

So I expect that when I call `get` with a key range, e.g. `IDBKeyRange.bound(0, 4)`, I should somehow receive four values when the request succeeds? But I only see a single value (tested in Chromium). Is this wrong documentation or wrong implementation, or am I missing a way to access all results without doing multiple requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `get(query)`
>
> The query parameter may be a [key](https://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#key) or an [IDBKeyRange](https://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#idbkeyrange) identifying the [record](https://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#object-store-record) to be retrieved. **If a range is specified, the method retrieves the first existing value in that range**.
>
> -- [IndexedDB API 2.0 - W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#ref-for-current-realm:%7E:text=The%20query%20parameter%20may%20be%20a%20key%20or%20an%20IDBKeyRange%20identifying%20the%20record%20to,first%20existing%20value%20in%20that%20range.)

* Emphasis mine.

To get all the values, use [`IDBObjectStore.getAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBObjectStore/getAll) instead of `.get()` or [`IDBObjectStore.openCursor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBObjectStore/openCursor):

> ```js
> function displayData() {
>   var keyRangeValue = IDBKeyRange.bound("A", "F");
>
>   var transaction = db.transaction(['fThings'], 'readonly');
>   var objectStore = transaction.objectStore('fThings');
>
>   objectStore.openCursor(keyRangeValue).onsuccess = function(event) {
>     var cursor = event.target.result;
>     if(cursor) {
>       var listItem = document.createElement('li');
>       listItem.innerHTML = '<strong>' + cursor.value.fThing + '</strong>, ' + > cursor.value.fRating;
>       list.appendChild(listItem);
>
>       cursor.continue();
>     } else {
>       console.log('Entries all displayed.');
>     }
>   };
> }
> ```
>
> -- [IDBKeyRange - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBKeyRange)